# Move Files to another folder based on part of file name

Tags: powershell

Hello Power Shell Champs,

I have a situation.

I have around 100 files with country name examples in C:\reports as:

- Report File-USA.ppt
- Report File-Canada.ppt
- Report File-Brazil.ppt
- Report File-Chile.ppt

I have folders with country names also in the folder C:\Countries

What I want to do is move files based on Country name to respective folders based on the name of country.

I'm uable to create a loop that works.
Note: Destination folders are already created, just files need to be moved

Comment: Welcome to the site, Afsal. Can you show what you have written so far so we can help you in what problems you are encountering. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to ask questions on this website.

Comment: You have multiple answers posted, if you found any of these helpful please upvote or select one as an answer to your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Maigi mentioned, here is working code and it actually uses `Move-Item` as you requested in your original post rather than `Copy-Item`.

This code has been tested and works.

```
$list = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\reports\ -Name -File).Replace('Report File-','').Replace('.ppt','')

ForEach-Object ($item in $list) 
{
    Move-Item -Path "C:\reports\Report File-$($item).ppt" -Destination "C:\Countries\$($item)\"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always more than one method to accomplish a task in PowerShell:
This script

- splits the BaseName at the hyphen, and takes the second part(zero based)
- if the destination path doesn't exist it is created.

---

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\reports\Report File-*.ppt' -File | ForEach-Object{
  $Country = Join-Path "C:\Country" $($_.BaseName.split('-')[1])
  If (!(Test-path $Country)) {mkdir $Country|Out-Null}
  $_|Move-Item -Destination $Country -whatif
}
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-whatif`

Answer (score -1):

Although some code from your side to see how far you've come would have been helpful, I imagine something like this should do the trick:
(edited)

```
$list = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\reports\ -Name -File).Replace('Report File-','').Replace('.ppt','')

foreach ($item in $list) {
Move-Item -Source ".\Report File-$($item).ppt" -Destination "C:\Countries\$($item)\"
}
```